# Simple Convert.ToDouble will cause wrong input string Error

Tags: c#

Here is my simple code:

```
string t = "65.2";
var d = Convert.ToDouble(t);
```

and it gives me this error:

`input string was not in a correct format` on `Convert.ToDouble`

I have tried `Convert.ToDobule(t, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` and also `Convert.ToDobule(t, new CultureInfo("en-US"));` it works fine on my machine, but on another with the same culture it will give the same error.

where is the problem? and how to solve it?

Comment: You're probably in a culture where the decimal separator is `,`, not `.`. Try specifying a culture where the decimal separator is `.` such as the invariant culture, e.g. `Convert.ToDouble(t, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: As and addition to @canton7, I wuld prefer double.TryParse. ie:  double.TryParse("65.2", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), out double v);
 Console.WriteLine(v);

Comment: @CetinBasoz If you're going to use `TryParse`, check the return result before using `v`! But agreed, `double.Parse` / `double.TryParse` is preferable to the `Convert` methods

Comment: @canton7, yes I meant to check but in comments it was even bad for a small piece of code:)

Comment: I have tried `Convert.ToDobule(t, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` and also `Convert.ToDobule(t, new CultureInfo("en-US"));` it works fine on my machine, but on another with the same culture it will give the same error I mentioned in question :(

Comment: @canton7 I have updated my question

Comment: I believe you are hiding the actual input value and code. That wouldn't cause such an error. Also, as I said, prefer TryParse instead.

Comment: @CetinBasoz The actual code is the same. I did not hide anything. it is so simple and I can not find the problem. I even checked both system languages settings. They are the same.

Comment: That code wouldn't cause such an error message. Maybe your error is coming from a nother part of your code?